# Scrapy help scraping after logging into a page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a table that comes after a login page using scrapy. The Login page is http://subscribers.footballguys.com/amember/login.php, and the webpage I am trying to scrape is https://subscribers.footballguys.com/myfbg/myweeklycheatsheet.php.

I have tried to follow the tutorials [from scrapy's documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin) as well as [here](https://python.gotrained.com/scrapy-formrequest-logging-in/), but I am not getting any responses back (not even the hello world). Below is my code. I can also provide any other information needed. Thank you in advance!

```
import scrapy


class FbgQbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fbg_qb'
    allowed_domains = ['www.footballguys.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://subscribers.footballguys.com/amember/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'amember_login': 'example@gmail.com', 'amember_pass': 'examplepassword'},
            callback=self.after_login
            )

    def after_login(self, response):
        #check login success before going on
        View(response)
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        fetch("https://subscribers.footballguys.com/myfbg/myweeklycheatsheet.php")
        players = response.css("span::text").extract()

        for item in zip(players):
            scraped_info = {
                'player' : item[0]
                }
            yield scraped_info
            print("hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

`hello world` is not printing because of an indentation issue.

[image]